# Return dynamic data to user profile when user login in Asp.Net Identity Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm currently trying to add a dynamic data to user profile. when user send login data (password flow) that included a string data, is there a way to add that data as a claim field in user profile?

Comment: I believe this may be helpful: https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-adding-claims-to-existing-identity/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).